# Batch script with eclipse: insert a string in file name

Tags: javascript, eclipse, batch-file

I'm following [this page](http://nicolas.debarnot.com/2009/12/minimizing-javascript-and-css-in-eclipse/) to compress css and JS files in my django project. The given instructions in the page are:

```
@echo off
set inputfile=%1
set outputfile=%inputfile:.src=%
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar %inputfile% -o %outputfile% --charset utf-8 --nomunge
```

This script helps to generate **.js/.css** files from **.src.js/.src.css** files. However, What I need to do is generate **.min.js/.min.css** from **.js/.css**. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set inputfile=%1
set outputfile=%inputfile:.js/.css=.min.js/min.css%
echo java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar %inputfile% -o %outputfile% --charset utf-8 --nomunge
```